# Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

The code below is used when the user enters a youtube url it get the youtube id from the url. It then get the title for that video with that id. That is then inserted into a database and recalled to display the image of the video associated with that id.

if i use this youtube url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p64tAbP-nHE or and other youtube url. If the title of that youtube url contains a ' ie(2013 Ravens Rock Rally - Jonathan O'Callaghan & Gavin Sheehan - Stage 3) i get the error

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Callaghan & Gavin Sheehan - Stage 3'' at line 1

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include 'dataconnection.php';
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else        
        $url = $_POST['set_video'];
        parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $my_array_of_vars );

        $youtube_id = $my_array_of_vars['v'];

        $info = $_POST['set_desc'];

        $id = $my_array_of_vars['v'];
        $xmlData =  simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$id}?fields=title"));

        $title = (string)$xmlData->title;

        $sql="INSERT INTO videodetails SET id='null',youtube_id='$youtube_id',info='$title'";

        if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection)); 
          }
        echo "<div id='pageheader'>
                1 record added<span id='logout'>Return to <a href='contributors_login.html'>Contributors Login</a></span>  
             </div>";

        echo '<div id="setvideo"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$my_array_of_vars['v'].'" target="_blank"><img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/'.$my_array_of_vars['v'].'/default.jpg" style="border:solid 2px white;"></a><p>'.$title.'</p></div>';

    mysqli_close($connection);  
?>
```

Comment: you need to do some escaping

Comment: You might find it helpful to view the contents of your $sql variable.

Comment: @Alan, don't forget to accept (tick) the answer you found most useful. Feel free to +1 any you like too, it's a good way of rewarding answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your yourTube name has a quote in it, so the SQL line

```
$sql="INSERT INTO videodetails SET id='null',youtube_id='$youtube_id',info='$title'
```

becomes this

```
INSERT INTO videodetails SET id='null',
   youtube_id='2013 Ravens Rock Rally - Jonathan O'Callaghan & Gavin Sheehan - Stage 3'
```

which MySQL sees as

```
INSERT INTO videodetails SET id='null',
   youtube_id='2013 Ravens Rock Rally - Jonathan O',Callaghan & Gavin Sheehan - Stage 3'
```

and MySQL doesn't understand **Callaghan & Gavin Sheehan - Stage 3'**

Comment: Also, `SET` isn't valid syntax for the `INSERT` statement. Edit: eek, apparently MySQL supports it! I'll have to eat my hat.

Comment: @halfer, right MySQL supports `SET` in `INSERT` statements, even though this is not standard SQL and won't necessarily work in other brands of RDBMS.  Cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 3):

Use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in your `INSERT INTO ...` part.

You open single quotes. But the title contains also single quotes so they get closed. MySQL doesn't know this and thinks the text that follows is a MySQL keyword.

Comment: since the OP is using `mysqli_*` not `mysql_*` it would be better to put [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: is this what you mean   $sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO videodetails SET id='null',youtube_id='$youtube_id',info='%s'",
   mysql_real_escape_string($title));

Comment: `$sql="INSERT INTO videodetails SET id='null',youtube_id='".mysqli_real_escape_string($youtube_id)."',info='".mysqli_real_escape_string($title)."'";`

Answer (score 2):

The case of strings that contain quotes is why mysqli_real_escape_string() exists, to find those quotes and insert a `\` before them so they count as literal quote characters, instead of terminating the quoted string.

```
. . .
$youtube_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($my_array_of_vars['v']);
$info = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['set_desc']);

$sql="INSERT INTO videodetails SET id='null',youtube_id='$youtube_id',info='$title'";

if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
. . .
```

But the best practice is to use query parameters, so you don't need to worry about those embedded quotes.  Any place you have a variable in your SQL string in place of a literal value, use a query parameter placeholder.  These placeholders don't work in place of table names, column names, or SQL expressions or keywords -- they only work where you would normally put a *single scalar value* in your SQL.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO videodetails SET id='null',youtube_id=?,info=?";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $youtube_id, $title);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

This is safer, and makes your SQL more readable.  Notice that the `?` placeholder itself *doesn't* go inside quotes, even if the value you bind to it is a string.

PS: I question your use of the quoted string `'null'` where you may mean the SQL keyword `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Your insert query is not valid sql.  The keyword "set" is used with update queries.  Insert queries look like this:

```
insert into atable
(f1, f2, etc)
values
(val1, val2, etc)
```

or this

```
insert into atable
(f1, f2, etc)
select val1, val2, etc
from someOtherTables
```

Comment: It's not standard SQL, but it's supported in MySQL.

Comment: `INSERT ... SET` is valid mysql syntax. see 2nd example http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: Upvoted - I didn't know MySQL supports this, but nevertheless, there's no reason not to use standard SQL here.

Comment: The bigger issue is that the OP has unescaped single quotes in his values - `... Jonathan O'Callaghan ...` so even if they change the syntax the query would still fail.